# Convergence of $\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{t^q}{1+t^q}dt; q\in{\mathbb{R}}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

How do i proceed to check the convergence\absolute convergence of the integral $$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{t^q}{1+t^q}dt; q\in{\mathbb{R}}.$$ Can anyone help me with this please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $q>0$ then
$$\frac{t^q}{1+t^q}\sim_\infty 1$$
and then the integral is divergent. The same result is clear for $q=0$.

Now if $q<0$ then
$$\frac{t^q}{1+t^q}\sim_\infty t^q$$
and the integral
$$\int_1^\infty t^qdt$$
is convergent if and only if $-q>1\iff q<-1$.

**Conclusion:** the given integral is convergent only if $q<-1$.

Comment: what is the meaning of the sign $\sim_{\infty}$?

Comment: $\sim_\infty$: asymptotic equivalent. We have
$$f\sim_\infty g\iff\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1$$

Comment: Very nice write-up!